# Div Content Width (Spillage Issue)

Tags: html, css

[image]

**Problem** :Main Content and Footer does not grow at 100% width.

**CSS Code;**

```
div.header{width:100%; height:50px;};
div.headercontent{width:980px; margin:0 auto;};
div.maincontent{width:100%;};
div.footer{width:100%; height:50px;}
```

Comment: Make fiddle man how can we solve this?

Comment: did u tried display:block;

Comment: Add please HTML structure

Comment: define  width on body OR div with header, footer and content inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/3dzH2/2/

You might want to remove the semicolon after each CSS declaration:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div.header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #b6ff00;
}
div.headercontent {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.maincontent {
    background: #ff7f27;
}
div.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And the HTML I assume you are using (as you haven't provided any):

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headercontent">
        Header    
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="maincontent">
    Main Content
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

Comment: It does for me in every browser I've tested it on. Explain why it doesn't work and what it doesn't work in so I can continue to help.

Comment: This works . Thanks for everything .

Answer (score 0):

Remove ";" after rule declaration